# How do I avoid color distortion of uploaded images?

Tags: images

When uploading image files to the Wordpress media library the colors are occasionally distorted.

This is especially noticeable in the blue tones. I think it is due to a missing conversion of the color space.

Does anyone know what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use standard color profiles, and convert your color profile to sRGB (in Photoshop -> Save for the web -> convert to sRGB checkbox).

You should also set quality compression to 100

```
add_filter('jpeg_quality', function($arg){return 100;});
```

Comment: Is it possible to convert images to sRGB when they are uploaded? Some of my customers uploaded their logos and they are displayed in wrong colors.

Comment: You may try this plugin:
[Color Space Fixer](https://github.com/CreunaFI/color-space-fixer)

Comment: Thank you, thats what i was looking for.